# multiple cancel controlID on modal popup extender

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, extender

my modal popup works fine and there is the one button I have placed at the bottom to close it. Within the popup box is a page that scroll for a a couple of pages and I would like to have close button at the top of the page as well to close the popup. I already tried to add CancelControlID="btn4Cancel" and it said only one cancelcontrolid was possible. So is there any other way to place an additional button on the popup that will close it?

<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup3" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExt3" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup3" PopupControlID="pnlpopup3" CancelControlID="btn3Cancel"  X="250" Y="150">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup3" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="500px" Width="570px" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">




<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udptitle3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

<asp:Label ID="lbltitle3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

</asp:UpdatePanel>